# SQL Server find all computed and non persisted columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find all the computed columns and not persisted. I looked at the `INFROMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` as well as `sys.columns`. I can't find `ispersisted` property in those tables. I also tried `COLUMNPROPERY()` with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188744.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in `sys.computed_columns` table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.computed_columns 
WHERE is_persisted = 0   -- for not persisted columns
```